# Flutter/Firebase : How can i access the current user without using '.then(...)' function

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

I'm trying to avoid using the `.then((u) { return u.uid })` function in all my code where I need to access the current user's UID, instead just by calling `getCurrentUser().uid` for a much faster access. However, it gives me an error `The getter 'uid' was called on null.` but it's not null because it does print in the console but only after showing that it's null and the error at the end for some reason. I'm not well knowledge in the Future/Async/Await logic so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
class UsersAPI {
  final DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(Config.users);

  Future<FirebaseUser> currentUser() async {
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  }

  FirebaseUser getCurrentUser() {
    FirebaseUser user;

    this.currentUser().then((u) {
      user = u;
      print('USER 1 $user'); // Prints after 'USER 2'
    });

    print('USER 2 $user'); // Prints first

    if (user != null) {
      return user;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  DatabaseReference getCurrentUserRef() {
    return this.usersRef.child(this.getCurrentUser().uid); // GIVES THE 'uid' WAS CALLED ON NULL ERROR
  }

  observeCurrentUser(Function onSuccess(User u)) {
    this.usersRef.child(this.getCurrentUser().uid).onValue.listen( (event) { // GIVES THE 'uid' WAS CALLED ON NULL ERROR
      DataSnapshot snapshot = event.snapshot;

      if (snapshot.value != null) {
        User user = User().transform(snapshot.key, snapshot.value);
        onSuccess(user);
      }
    });
  }

  observeUser(String userID, Function onSuccess(User u), Function onFailure(String e)) {
    this.usersRef.child(userID).onValue.listen( (e) {
      DataSnapshot snapshot = e.snapshot;
      if (snapshot.value != null) {
        User user = User().transform(snapshot.key, snapshot.value);
        onSuccess(user);
      } else {
        onFailure("User Not Found...");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Example Usage - WORKS:

```
APIs().usersAPI.currentUser().then((u) {
  APIs().usersAPI.observeUser(u.uid, (u) {
    onSuccess(u);
  }, (e) {
    print(e);
  });
});
```

DOESN'T WORK:

```
APIs().usersAPI.observeCurrentUser((u) {
  onSuccess(u);
});
```

Comment: you need to return a `Future<FirebaseUser>` and use it as a Future. So you'll either need to use `then()` or `await`.

Comment: The whole point is to avoid using `then()` in all my codes when I simply need to access what's within it. I added examples that work and what doesn't work. The code the doesn't work is what I'm aiming at. Trying to reduce as much lines of code as I can.

Comment: You can't make an async function become async magically. If you call an async method and want to wait for its result, the whole call hierarchy becomes async.

Comment: If you want to reduce the amount of nesting/lines of code, you may want to look into `await`.

Comment: No but why isn’t my getCurrentUser() function working I’m calling in there but it doesn’t get called till after the rest of the code is run

Comment: This line `return this.usersRef.child(this.getCurrentUser().uid);` will never work since `getCurrentUser()` returns a `Future` and not a `FirebaseUser`.

Comment: The line `if (user != null) {` will most likely always evaluate to `true`, because the `user` variable will not be initialized, because its initialization happens in an async method called that's not being awaited.

Answer (score 0):

```
  DatabaseReference getCurrentUserRef() async {
    return this.usersRef.child((await this.getCurrentUser()).uid); =
  }
```

than call

`var ref = await getCurrentUserRef()`

Little bit more pretty

```
  DatabaseReference getCurrentUserRef() async {
    var firebaseUser = await this.getCurrentUser();
    return this.usersRef.child(firebaseUser.uid); 
  }
```

EDIT: to clarify some question on asynchronicity

How would you call now this function to get the reference?

Lets say you want to update the data on the user, you can do

```
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
  var reference = await getCurrentUserRef();
  await transaction.set(reference, someData);
  });
```

Or you would like to read the data from that reference

```
readAndProcessData() async {
  var reference = await getCurrentUserRef();
  DocumentSnapshot user = await reference.get();
  print(user.data.toString);
}
```

Comment: in your second example `uid` doesn't equal a uid, but a `FirebaseUser`

Comment: I can't use async/await without returning a `Future<Type>`  so I can't really use it without calling `.then()`

Comment: If you still think you need to use `.then` can you explain in what case and why?

Comment: Just when you call the api, you need to do it with await to get your result

Comment: You clearly can't use async/await without returning a `Future` (or without marking your function `async`, which is effectively the same).